# Updating An Event By Dragging/Dropping FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Hello I am trying to implement drag and drop feature which is available in fullcalendar. It is working but I'm facing a problem that whenever I try to drag and drop and event it moves that event to the new location but it also moves all the other ahead to. I don't know why I am facing this error.Here is my code

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        // put your options and callbacks here
        // droppable: true,
        editable: true,
        eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
            alert(event.title + " was dropped on " + event.start.format());

            // if (!confirm("Are you sure about this change?")) {
            //     revertFunc();
            // }
        },        
     //    drop: function(date) {
     //     alert("Dropped on " + date.format());
        // },
        viewRender: function (view) {
                debugger;
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: base_url +"/apps/calendar/getByMonth",
                async : false,
                dataType: 'html',
                data: {'type': $('#formName').val() },
                success: function(mark_up){
                  debugger;
                  mark_up = JSON.parse(mark_up);
                  my_events = mark_up["task"];
                  $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'removeEvents');
                  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', my_events);
                }
            });
        },
        eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

            // alert('Event: ' + calEvent.title);
            // alert('Coordinates: ' + jsEvent.pageX + ',' + jsEvent.pageY);
            // alert('View: ' + view.name);
            $('#eventId').val(calEvent._id.$id);
            $('#editStarts').val(calEvent.start._i);
            if (calEvent.end == null){
                $('#editEnds').val(calEvent.start._i);
            }else{
                $('#editEnds').val(calEvent.end._i);
            }
            $('#editTitle').val(calEvent.title);
            $('#editDescription').val(calEvent.description);
            $('#editNewEvent').modal('show')
            // change the border color just for fun
            // $(this).css('border-color', 'red');

        },
         dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {

            // var p = date.month()+'/'+date.day()+'/'+date.year()
             $('#addNewEvent').modal('show');
            // alert('a day has been clicked!');
        }
```

Here is a link to the problem I am facing. [Drag Problem](http://screencast.com/t/IHDSYgj9b)

I am sorry for sharing like this but I didn't know how to show you guys my problem and this is the only way that came to mind

Comment: this may happen if your events all have the same id.

Comment: @Kito how will I find out that since all the rendering is being done by full calendar itself.

Comment: you can find the id of each event with "calEvent._id". Your code looks like you are pulling your events through an AJAX call and that your events are stored in "my_events". Does each event in "my_events" have an id? Could you maybe add a sample of how "my_events" looks like?